# Add controls to custom dialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show a dialog with ~50 custom controls (switch buttons) on it. So, the best way to do that is to add them programmatically in a loop. I've tried to make a dilog with a layout wich contains the only one GroupView element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ViewGroup
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/dlg_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then just add my controls in it using: onCreateDialog(...) method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.geomap_menu, null))
          .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 // sign in the user ...
              }
          })
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  //LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
              }
});

Dialog res = builder.create();
ViewGroup dlgView = (ViewGroup)res.findViewById(R.id.dlg_view);
MyControl myControl = new MyControl(this);
dlgView.add(myControl);
```

But it doesn't work this way (it throws InflateException). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using `LayoutInflater`

Comment: please give some more details. More code where you inflate... code about MyController and a detailed Error log output with. It would be best if you mark the line, where the error occurs.

Comment: code updated... Error occurs in <inflater.inflate(R.layout.geomap_menu, null)> ...

Comment: Move the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` before any other line with `android:something` where you declare the `LinearLayout` in the xml layout, like `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...`.

Comment: @Luksprog What the difference? Anyway, it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post the exception you get?

Comment: You mean .apk file?  It's too big and it uses remote resources which are available only locally. BTW, Is my solution correct?

Comment: When your app crashes you can see the stacktrace of the exception in the `Logcat`(a bunch of red lines). That is what I'm asking you to post so I can see exactly what is the problem with your code.

Comment: There is no red line (or any other output about this crash) in watchcat... Only InflateException in main thread in Debug window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems in your code were pretty obvious:

- In your layout file you use `ViewGroup` which is an abstract class(the root of all layouts in Android) and which can't be instantiated so it will most likely be the reason for that inflate exception you talk about. Use one of the subclasses of `ViewGroup`, like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc, which one fits you better.
- Even after doing the modification I wrote above your code will still bot work. First the `ViewGroup` class doesn't have an `add` method, you're probably referring to one of the `addView` methods. Second the `dlgView` will be `null` because at that moment the `Dialog` isn't displayed so there is no `View` to find. You can do it by posting a `Runnable` on one of your views to delay setting the views until the `Dialog` is shown:

  ```
  final Dialog res = builder.create();
  oneOfYourViews.post(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          ViewGroup dlgView = (ViewGroup) res.findViewById(R.id.dlg_view);
          MyControl myControl = new MyControl(context);
          dlgView.addView(myControl);             
      }
  });
  ```

Code addition:

```
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geomap_menu, null)
ViewGroup dlgView = (ViewGroup) contentView.findViewById(R.id.dlg_view);
MyControl myControl = new MyControl(this);
dlgView.addView(myControl); // or add the other views in the loop as many as you want
builder.setView(contentView);
// rest of your code
```

Comment: That was kind of pseudocode and my question was not about mistakes in my code, but "How to add controls to custom dialog programatically". So, I'm sure there should be only one right way to do that.

Comment: @Tutankhamen I don't understand why you posted pseudocode and then asked why did you get that exception. There is no problem(and no single right way) on adding widgets to a dialog, the right way depends on what, how and from where do you want to add those widgets. Regarding your code, don't set the view directly to the dialog, inflate the layout, add the views in a loop and then set it to the dialog.

Comment: I just said that I've tried that way, but it doesn't work, so, may be some body know how to make it right. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what I was asking for!